# I broke my internet after tethering wifi with phone over usb

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, usb, android, tethering

So a while ago, I was at a house with my laptop and my phone. I wanted to access the wifi on my computer, so I plugged in my phone via USB and activated USB tethering on my nexus 5. Worked like a charm. Later upon returning home I find that I cannot access any sites besides www.google.com. All other sites return a server not found. If I run the network over my phone though, it works fine.

Process:

1. Was to lazy to get wifi password
2. Tethered phone to laptop via USB
3. Internet works!
4. Return home wifi connects
5. home wifi does not let me connect to any other sites besides google.com
6. Works fine when tethered over phone.
7. Tried this out at other locations. No matter what I can only connect to google.com using my computers wifi adapter.
8. This is not practical. Does anyone have a suggestion on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

To fix simply remove phone tethering drivers. Do not have your phone plugged in when doing this: Open up a run dialog, type devmgmt.msc, go to "Network Adapters". Right click on the tethering adapter, click uninstall, make sure you hit uninstall and not disable otherwise it will not work. If by any chance you uninstalled the wrong driver, just hit the "Scan" button at the top and it will reinstall it.